# Removing custom post type name from permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, slug

There are numerous threads on this, however, none of them seem to resolve the issue for me.

#### Background

I have a custom post type called "Landing pages", which has been registered like this:

```
register_post_type(
  'Landing pages',
  theme_build_post_args(
    // $slug, $singular, $plural
    'landing-pages', 'Landing pages', 'Landing pages',
    array(
      'menu_position' => 20,
      'has_archive'     => false,
      'public'          => false,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
      'supports'    => array('title', 'revisions'),
      'rewrite' => array(
        'with_front' => false,
        'slug' => '/'
      ),
    )
  )
);
```

What I'm trying to do is remove `landing-pages` from the permalinks when creating posts in this post type. For example I have a post which sits on `/landing-pages/test`. I want this to simply be `/test`.

#### What I've tried

**Approach 1:**

```
'public' => false, 
'publicly_queryable' => true, 
'show_ui' => true, 
'exclude_from_search' => true,
'show_in_nav_menus' => false, 
'has_archive' => false, 
'rewrite' => false,
```

**Approach 2:**

Remove slug via functions (`functions.php`):

```
function na_remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {
  if ( 'Landing pages' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
      return $post_link;
  }
  $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );
  return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'na_remove_slug', 10, 3 );


function na_parse_request( $query ) {
  if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
    return;
  }

  if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'Landing pages', 'page' ) );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'na_parse_request' );
```

**Approach 3:**

```
'rewrite' => array(
  'with_front' => false,
  'slug' => '/'
),
```

Comment: Try this - https://michaelbox.net/2020/06/slugless-post-type-permalinks/